# Recyclerview with horizontal items as it was a table?

Tags: java, android, sqlite

My app has a database where are stored 12 columns that cointains text added by the user 
I am able to retrive and put data in the recycle view using an array list but the result is a line-by-line list an element after another 
I want the 12 element allineated horizontally and then another 13 element as a new line,I tried putting a \n in the array list but the result is an horizontal space followed by other 13 elements
For this I used :

```
LinearLayoutManager layoutManager= new LinearLayoutManager(this,RecyclerView.HORIZONTAL,false);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
```

This is the code that loads the the columns in the array list and puts the in the recycleview:

```
public class VisualizzaPunto extends AppCompatActivity implements MyRecyclerViewAdapter.ItemClickListener {

    private PuntoStradaDatabase helper;
    private MyRecyclerViewAdapter adapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_visualizza_punto);
        helper = new PuntoStradaDatabase(this);
        RecyclerView recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recycle);
        LinearLayoutManager layoutManager= new LinearLayoutManager(this);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
        SQLiteDatabase db = helper.getReadableDatabase();
        ArrayList<String> theList = new ArrayList<>();
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM PUNTOSTRADA", null);
        while(cursor.moveToNext()){
            theList.add(cursor.getString(1));
            theList.add(cursor.getString(2));
            theList.add(cursor.getString(3));
            theList.add(cursor.getString(4));
            theList.add(cursor.getString(5));
            theList.add(cursor.getString(6));
            theList.add(cursor.getString(7));
            theList.add(cursor.getString(8));
            theList.add(cursor.getString(9));
            theList.add(cursor.getString(10));
            theList.add(cursor.getString(11));
            theList.add(cursor.getString(12));
            theList.add("\n");
        }
       /* DividerItemDecoration dividerItemDecoration = new DividerItemDecoration(recyclerView.getContext(),
                layoutManager.getOrientation());
        recyclerView.addItemDecoration(dividerItemDecoration);
      */  adapter = new MyRecyclerViewAdapter(this, theList);
        adapter.setClickListener(this);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);



    }

    public void onItemClick(View view, int position) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "You clicked " + adapter.getItem(position) + " on row number " + position, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

This is the adapter code:

```
public class MyRecyclerViewAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MyRecyclerViewAdapter.ViewHolder> {
    private List<String> mData;
    private LayoutInflater mInflater;
    private ItemClickListener mClickListener;

    // data is passed into the constructor
    MyRecyclerViewAdapter(Context context, List<String> data) {
        this.mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        this.mData = data;
    }

    // inflates the row layout from xml when needed
    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.recyclerview_row1, parent, false);
        return new ViewHolder(view);
    }

    // binds the data to the TextView in each row
    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        String item = mData.get(position);
        holder.myTextView.setText(item);
    }

    // total number of rows
    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return mData.size();
    }


    // stores and recycles views as they are scrolled off screen
    public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {
        TextView myTextView;

        ViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            myTextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.row1);
            itemView.setOnClickListener(this);
        }

        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            if (mClickListener != null) mClickListener.onItemClick(view, getAdapterPosition());
        }
    }

    // convenience method for getting data at click position
    String getItem(int id) {
        return mData.get(id);
    }

    // allows clicks events to be caught
    void setClickListener(ItemClickListener itemClickListener) {
        this.mClickListener = itemClickListener;
    }

    // parent activity will implement this method to respond to click events
    public interface ItemClickListener {
        void onItemClick(View view, int position);
    }
}
```

do you have any suggestions to show data in a human-readable way? Thanks in advance and sorry for my incompetence but I am still learning

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use GridLayoutManager https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/recyclerview/widget/GridLayoutManager.html instead of a LinearLayoutManager

Or if you want an layout Manger that adapts to the size of the screen use a FlexboxLayoutManager

https://github.com/google/flexbox-layout

If there is too much you want to fit in a row or column to fit on the screen then wrap the recyclerview view with `GridLayoutManager` in a `HorizontalScrollView` or `ScrollView` to scroll the recyclerview in the direction it does not scroll

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/HorizontalScrollView

and

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ScrollView.html

So it sounds like you want a RecyclerView in Vertical Orientation with a Grid layout manager with the columns set to 12 all wrapped up in a Horizontal Scroll View so you can scroll to the column off the screen to the right.

Comment: I used the flexbox-layout menager but I have the same problem but the problem is always the same,there just isn't room for 12 columns and the reycle view refuses to scrool horizontally The code now changed to:
        FlexboxLayoutManager layoutManager = new FlexboxLayoutManager(this);
        layoutManager.setFlexWrap(FlexWrap.NOWRAP);
        layoutManager.setFlexDirection(FlexDirection.ROW);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);

Comment: Recyclerview will only scroll in one direction no matter what layout manager you use. If the number of columns you want is too big for the screen then you need to wrap the Recyclerview in a Scroll View.